# convert rsyslog message format when forwarding messages with structured-data

Tags: linux, logging, syslog, rsyslog

My daemon uses libc `syslog()` call that logs messages in `RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat` format. And, rsyslogd daemon running on the same host needs to forward all these messages to a remote log collector in `RSYSLOG_SyslogProtocol23Format` format.

Now I want to "piggy back" `%STRUCTURED-DATA%` to `RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat` format (basically when my daemon will call `syslog()` it will specify structured data in square brackets). **How can I specify incoming log message format (or template) in rsyslog.conf so that it would understand structured-data?**

I understand that one of the solutions would be for my daemon to directly send message to `/dev/log` and change default log message format in `rsyslog.conf`. However, this does not seem right, because I want to keep the local log format the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it is impossible to solve this in an elegant way, because libc `syslog()` call uses `/dev/log` UNIX domain socket.

And rsyslog 8.8 and older uses hardcoded message parser for messages received over UNIX domain socket. See usespecialparser setting (http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/imuxsock.html)

Another option to get this to work with the latest Ubuntu 15.04 that ships with rsyslog 7.4 would be to use UDP socket, but then I can't use libc `syslog()` anymore.